# JavaScript redirect using iframe and cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I am doing a simple redirect, using JavaScript code like `window.location="http://google.com`,

When the page initially gets loaded, I can see a cookie, but on redirect  this cookie is not sent?

I am using an `iframe` to display my page and redirect to different page. Just wanted to know how to set a cookie on redirect using JavaScript?

Comment: you can store cookie for you domain only

Comment: Do you want to set the cookie for the page you are redirecting to or for the redirecting page? The first can't work, as you are restricted to your own domain ...

Comment: yes, i want to set a cookie to for the redirecting page

Comment: @user1224036 Well, then the answer is simple: you can't: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Cookie_security